# Symfony 2 doesn't generate web/bundle/framework structure

Tags: php, css, symfony

I have a huge problem with Symfony. I installed **Symfony 2.7.5** from command line:

```
$ symfony new my_project
```

But the main problem is that all project was generated correctly with the exception of directory: **/web/bundle**

So I have in this folder two empty files (not catalogues!) with **0 KB** size: **framework** and **sensiodistribution**. That means all Symfony error pages haven't any css style and look ugly.

**Screens:**

> ***My local folder:***
>   [image]

and

> **Error page:**
>
> [image]

What should I do?

Comment: Might be the version. Try with 2.7.4. Or try that and a composer update. Maybe you got an error while you've installed it that you miss.

Comment: There is no web/bundle directory.  Did you mean web/bundles?  It get's populated when you run app/console assets:install or app/console assetic:dump

Comment: @Cerad Yes, I mean web/bundles. run app/console assets:install was helpfull, everything works fine! Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command:

```
$ app/console assets:install
```

populated this catalogue and it was the solution of the problem.